# If $h_n\to h$ in the norm then $h_n\to h$ weakly

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that if $h_n\to h$ in norm then $h_n\to h$ weakly. Also, show that the converse is false, but if $h_n\to h$ weakly and $\|h_n\|\to \|h\|$, then $h_n\to h$ in norm.

I assume that by "convergence in norm" they mean that for $\epsilon >0, \exists N$ such that $\|h_n - h\|\leq\epsilon$?

If that is true, then for the first part I am thinking...

Since $h_n\to h$ in norm, then $lim_{n\to\infty}h_n = h$, so

$$lim_{n\to\infty}<h_n,g>=<lim_{n\to\infty}h_n,g>=<h,g>$$ and therefore $h_n\to h$ weakly?

Comment: You're right about the first part. The equalities you wrote are valid for all $g$ in the dual because $g$ is continuous.

Comment: The second part is valid in a uniformly convex Banach space.

Comment: Are you working in a Hilbert space? If so, see, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249420/convergence-in-weak-topology-implies-convergence-in-norm-topology). If not, you should tell what space you are working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming from your notation you are working in Hilbert spaces; the first result is true in general Banach spaces too (with fairly easy adaptations). For the first part you have the right idea (it's true in general Banach spaces, but I assume from your notation you are working in Hilbert spaces) but the presentation could be better (and you haven't said what $g$ is); I would prefer the following:

> Suppose $h_n \rightarrow h$ in norm. Fix $g \in H$. Then, as $z \mapsto  \langle z , g \rangle$ is continuous,
>
> $$lim_{n\to\infty} \langle h_n,g \rangle= \langle h,g \rangle$$ and therefore $h_n\to h$ weakly.

An example to show that weak convergence does not imply convergence in norm is taking the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$, and the sequence $f_n(x)=\sin (2 n \pi x) + 1$. You get $\langle f_n , g \rangle \rightarrow \langle 1 , g \rangle$ for all $g$ continuous on $[0,1]$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, so it holds for all $h \in L^2[0,1]$ as continuous functions are dense in that space. However you don't get convergence to $1$ in norm, as $\| f_n - 1 \| = 1/\sqrt{2}$ for all $n$.

For the third part (convergence in norm plus weak convergence implying convergence in norm), you do require it to be a Hilbert space for the proof you are probably looking for. Just simply write out the norm squared; $$ \begin{align} \| f_n - f \|^2 &= \| f_n \|^2 - \langle f_n , f \rangle - \langle f , f_n \rangle + \| f \|^2 \\
&\rightarrow \| f \|^2 - \langle f , f \rangle - \langle f,f \rangle + \| f \|^2 \\
&= 0.\end{align} $$